# Sql query for following scenario

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have following scenario, for which i need to write sql query.

I have ICCID table  and ICCID property table which holds following information.

[image]

I want to find out all active iccids and iccid's which are in removed state in month of december 2012.for ICCIDs which are in removed state, `date.to.change` key in the ICCID property table itself which record the removed date of ICCID.

```
this is my attempt, but that did not worked
     select e.ID_ICCID from ICCID_PROPERTY e where 
     e.c_key ='STATE' and e.c_value='Active' or(
     e.c_key ='STATE' and 
     e.c_value='Removed' and
     e.c_key='date.to.change' and  
     to_date(e.c_value,'yyyymmdd')  >=to_date('2012-DEC-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
     to_date(e.c_value,'yyyymmdd')  <= to_date('2012-DEC-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')
     ))
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? if so post your attempts

Comment: yes, i updated question with my attempt also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the issues with a key-value pair design such as this...

You can't just check a single property row to see if it matches the search criteria, since the criteria in this case will span multiple properties... you have to check if a single parent row has all the children properties that match:

```
SELECT
    i.ICCID
FROM
    ICCID i
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ICCID_PROPERTY ip
        WHERE 
            ip.ID_ICCID = i.ID_ICCID
            AND ip.c_key = 'STATE'
            AND ip.c_value = 'Active'
    ) OR (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ICCID_PROPERTY ip
            WHERE 
                ip.ID_ICCID = i.ID_ICCID
                AND ip.c_key = 'STATE'
                AND ip.c_value = 'Removed'
        ) AND
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ICCID_PROPERTY ip
            WHERE 
                ip.ID_ICCID = i.ID_ICCID
                AND ip.c_key = 'date.to.change'
                AND to_date(ip.c_value,'yyyymmdd') >= 
                    to_date('2012-DEC-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                AND to_date(ip.c_value,'yyyymmdd') <= 
                    to_date('2012-DEC-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could join the Property table three times -- maybe something like this (untested):

```
SELECT I.ID_ICCID
FROM ICCID I
  JOIN ICCID_Property IP ON I.ID_ICCID = IP.ID_ICCID AND IP.C_Key = 'STATE' AND IP.C_Value = 'Active'
  JOIN ICCID_Property IP2 ON I.ID_ICCID = IP.ID_ICCID AND IP2.C_Key = 'STATE' AND IP2.C_Value= 'Removed'
  JOIN ICCID_Property IP3 ON I.ID_ICCID = IP.ID_ICCID AND IP3.C_Key = 'date.to.change' AND to_date(IP3.C_Value,'yyyymmdd') >= to_date('2012-DEC-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
            AND to_date(IP3.C_Value,'yyyymmdd') <= 
                to_date('2012-DEC-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Good luck.